# MacBook Pro 16 2019 + External Monitor. Battery Life

Tags: macbook-pro, display, battery

I've recently bought a MBP Pro 16' 2019. I'm using right now a Thunderbolt 2 adapter so I can connect it to an old iMac 21' and using as an external monitor.

My question is: It is safe for battery life keep it connected all the time?

Right now, I'm only working from Home (Pandemic) and I'm afraid of leaving it at power source all the time.

I don't mind when it hits 80% of battery charge, unplug and plug again when it's 30%. But just to clarify if it's correct.

Also, I'm planning on buying an LG Monitor with Thunderbolt 3, that has an 85W plug connector to provide energy to the MBP. Should I use it? The official charger is 96W.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it plugged in most of the time is fine, just make sure to unplug it about once every month. I'd recommend using the official charger, as Apple has reasons for making the charger 96W.

Comment: @WGroleau How should I improve the answer?

Comment: I must have accidentally flagged the wrong item.  I see nothing wrong with the original.  Although your added sentence does make it better.